# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 when trying to connect to AWS RDS (Postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I can't connect to my Postgres DB hosted on AWS. I'm trying to access it from a local Node server running on port 3000. Whenever I'm making an API call to the DB, i get the following error : `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)`.

This is where I connect to the DB:

```
require('dotenv').config
const { Pool } = require('pg')

const pool = new Pool({
    user: process.env.USER,
    host: process.env.DB,
    database: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    port: 5432,
})
module.exports = {
  getAll: (text, callback) => {
    return pool.query(text, callback)
  },
  query: (text, params, callback) => {
    return pool.query(text, params, callback)
  },
}
```

I have tried exposing the local port with ngrok, which made no difference.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: it shouldn't be `127.0.0.1` for the hostname if you are connecting the AWS RDS. can you share your postges connection config?

Comment: The .env file holds all the correct information necessary to connect to AWS. How/ where can i specify the host not to be `127.0.0.1`? the process.env.HOST specifies the AWS endpoint

Comment: you specified AWS endpoint in `process.env.HOST` but in the config above `host: process.env.DB`, it is using `DB`. should be `host: process.env.HOST, database: process.env.DB,` ?

Comment: This was a typo, process.env.DB hold the correct endpoint

Comment: I think may be your dotenv is not loaded correctly. can you try `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: it seems to be connecting now, but now I receive the error: `error: password authentication failed for user "username"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/.../node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)`

Comment: you db user is called `username`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232515/discussion-between-nico-and-mic-fung).

Comment: Did you find out what was causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**: `git archive -v -o myapp.zip --format=zip HEAD` doesn't update if you don't commit. Make sure you commit your changes before issuing the command.

---

I was changing the files, but they weren't *changing*. If you do not want to really commit, create a commit then rollback. It is useful to run `git archive` because it respects `.gitignore` and doesn't include the ignored files in the zip.

Make sure the `process.env.*` are:

```
RDS_HOSTNAME
RDS_USERNAME
RDS_PASSWORD
RDS_DB_NAME
```

Then `git commit` before issuing `git archive -v -o myapp.zip --format=zip HEAD`